# implementation of jeremy feinstein's SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-sliding

I'm trying to develop an application using Jeremy Feinstein's SlidingMenu library. All I have done in the right way as described in the Github instructions.  Everything is working well, but the problem is that when I click on action bar home button to open the slider it covers the complete screen.  I want it to open in half open like in Facebook slider in Facebook app. My code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Hide title bar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    //Enable home button
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    //Home as up display
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   // getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);

    //SlidingMenu menu=getSlidingMenu();
    SlidingMenu menu=new SlidingMenu(this);
    //menu = new SlidingMenu(MainActivity.this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
    menu.setShadowWidth(5);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.0f);
    menu.attachToActivity(MainActivity.this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setBehindWidth(10);
    menu.setBehindOffset(10);
    menu.setBehindScrollScale(0.25f);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);


}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `behindOffset`, `behindWidth` or `touchModeAbove`.
If you use it as a view you could do this (in your layout file):

```
sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/YOUR_OFFSET"
sliding:behindWidth="@dimen/YOUR_WIDTH"
sliding:touchModeAbove="margin"
```

**Further explained**

`touchModeAbove` - an enum that designates what part of the screen is touchable when the above view is showing. Margin means only the left margin. Fullscreen means the entire screen. Default is margin.

`behindOffset` - a dimension representing the number of pixels that you want the above view to show when the behind view is showing. Default is 0.

`behindWidth` - a dimension representing the width of the behind view. Default is the width of the screen (equivalent to behindOffset = 0).

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for your answer.I used it in my code and its work well now.

Answer (score -2):

IN YOUR CODE:

// SlidingMenu menu=getSlidingMenu();
    SlidingMenu menu=new SlidingMenu(this);

JUST REMOVE // ON FIRST LINE BECAUSE YOU NEED AN INSTANTIATED OBJETC AT THIS TIME.

REMOVE SECOND LINE, THATS ALL.
ON SECOND LINE YOU ARE INSTANTIATING A NEW OBJECT AND IT IS NOT NECESARY....SLIDING MENU OBJECT GETS INSTANTIATED ONCE YOU SET BEHIND CONTENT VIEW.

I GOT SAME TROUBLE AND SOLVE THIS OUT THAT WAY.